# How Do You Bind A View After Form Submit In AngularJS ng-submit?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms

I have a simple question. How do you bind a view after form submit in AngularJS? My controller has this function to test if the submission works:

```
var spinnrApp = angular.module('spinnrApp', ['ngAnimate', 'ui.router', 'slick']);

spinnrApp.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  //
  // Now set up the states
  $stateProvider
    .state('registration', {
      url: "/registration",
      templateUrl: "app/components/registration/registration.php",
      controller: "FormController"
    })
    .state('registration.spinnrapp', { // nested state for the registration form
      url: "/spinnrapp", // url will be nested /registration/artist
      templateUrl: "app/components/registration/partials/registration-profile.php"
    })
    .state('registration.artist', { // nested state for the registration form
      url: "/artist", // url will be nested /registration/artist
      templateUrl: "app/components/registration/partials/registration-artist.php"
    })
    .state('registration.share', { // each nested state will have their own view
      url: "/share", // url will be nested /registration/share
      templateUrl: "app/components/registration/partials/registration-share.php"
    });
    //
    // For any unmatched url, redirect to /
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/registration/spinnrapp");
});
spinnrApp.controller('FormController', ['$scope', '$http', function (scope, http){

  // get list of cities and store it to select
  http.get('cities.json').success(function(data){
    scope.cities = data;
  })

  // we will store all our form data in this object
  scope.formData = {};

  // function to process the form
  scope.processForm = function() {
    $state.go('registration.share');
  };
}]);
```

How do you change `alert("awesome!");` to a ui-view after ng-submit passes through? I have a ui-view called `registration-share.php`.

UPDATE: I am calling the `processForm` in the submit button like this:

```
<div class="form-group row">
  <div class="col-xs-3 col-xs-offset-1">
    <button type="submit" class="submit btn">Next Section</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

where my formApp wrapper goes like this:

```
<form id="signup-form" ng-submit="processForm()">
  <!-- our nested state views will be injected here -->
  <div id="form-views" ui-view></div>
</form>
```

Comment: are you using an Angular router such as ng-route or ui-router?

Comment: There is `$state.go` function that you can use.

Comment: Are you trying to submit the form to registration-share.php?

Comment: Martin, I'm trying to redirect the page to registration-share.php after submission succeeds. This is a static page.

Comment: You don't appear to be injecting $state into the controller.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you're using ui-router, **inject $state into the controller** and use the following:

```
$state.go('newUiRouterStateYouWishToDisplay');
```

---

This doesn't apply at this point, as you clarified that you're using ui-router, but
if you were using ngRoute, inject $location into the controller and use the follwing:

```
$location.path('/newNgRouteYouWishToDisplay');
```

Comment: I am using ui-router. I tried using `$state.go('registration.share');` but nothing happens. It's not redirecting to the page. `registration.share` is the state name of `/registration-share.php`. *EDIT: I updated my question and added more information.

Comment: I think you are confusing ui-router routes with server routes. "/registration-share.php" appears to be a server side route. The $state.go() function is to load a new Angular view. This will have the effect of changing what comes after the # in the URL and doesn't initiate any contact with the server. If you have defined a route to a php page, then you are likely confusing the two. Without more info about your routes and what you're trying to do, it's tough to know what to suggest.

Comment: typically, in the $scope.processForm() function, you would post to the server via $http, ngResource, Restangular, or some other ajax service. You do this instead of a traditional full page post to a server route. Upon completion, you would then initiate a $state.go() to change the view -- but it would be loading a static html template partial.

Comment: also, you need to inject $state into the controller. are you getting JS errors on the JS console?

Comment: I now added the entire app.js to my question. Please let me know what to do or how to approach this. Thanks!

Comment: Check your JS console for 404s when it tries to load the partial; also check for any other errors. Are you serving your static html partials through php? Do you realize that there will be no POST happening in your code? As a single page app, you have to initiate a POST in the processForm() function. Updating the view to a php page isn't going to have that effect. The routing is going to try to pull the "registration-share.php" file via GET and use it as a partial template. No processing of the input data will occur.

Comment: In your code, you don't appear to be injecting $state into the controller that is trying to use $state.go()

Comment: @ralphcarlo -- did it work once you injected $state? If this has helped, can you please award and upvote my answer.

Comment: Hi @Mike. state.go() did not work even after injecting $state.

Comment: Update: It worked. I just had some typos. I got this resolve just by using state.go. Thanks a lot!